# Number Class in java

Tags: java, serialization, abstract-class

Number class is an abstract class in which you cannot make objects from it using `new` operator, but we can use the class as reference Type, I want some explaination for the following code:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Number x = 3;
    System.out.println(x.intValue());
    System.out.println(x.doubleValue());
  }
}
```

**the output is 3 and 3.0**

So, in this line `Number x = 3;` is there any autoboxing or unboxing(which can't happen it's the superclass) happens? or what?
how the assignment happened here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `doubleValue` is `abstract` in `Number`, but you are storing an `Integer` (through [auto-boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_(computer_science))) when you do

```
Number x = 3; // This is Number x = Integer.valueOf(3);
```

And [`Integer.doubleValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#doubleValue--) says *Returns the value of this Integer as a double after a widening primitive conversion.* And it then refers the reader to [JLS-5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2). Which says, in part, *A widening primitive conversion does not lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value in the following cases, where the numeric value is preserved exactly:* and then lists (specific to this case) *from `int` to `double`*

Comment: I got this well, now I have a question, the following code is wrong because Number class doesn't have compareTo method, 
    ``  Number x = Integer.valueOf(3);
    System.out.println(x.intValue());
    System.out.println(x.compareTo(Integer.valueOf(4)));``

I mean how it can be while the Number x is Integer now ?

Comment: @Sarah_Sameh Because the code fails at compile time, not when running.  The *compiler* doesn’t try to run your whole program and determine all of the lines that may have assigned a value to `x`.  The compiler doesn’t know that `x` is only ever assigned an Integer.  The compiler only knows that the type of `x` is Number, and `x` may contain an object whose class has a compareTo method or may contain an object of a different subtype which does not have a compareTo method.

Comment: So, it's okay as concept but not applicable in compilation context?  
@VGR

Comment: @Sarah_Sameh It is certainly fine to store a value in a Number variable.  But if you wanted to be sure it was a Comparable value, you would declare `x` as an Integer.